# Print a #define macro using std::cout

Tags: c++, gcc9

I am trying to do this

```cpp
#define _TEST_ test
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        std::cout << "_TEST_" << std::endl;
}
```

As far as my understanding, I expect this output.

```
test
```

However, the output I get is

```
_TEST_
```

Why am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How is `"string literal"` different from `"_TEST_"`?

Comment: shouldn't `#define _TEST_ test` cause `_TEST_` to be read as `test`?

Comment: `#define _TEST_ "test" 
#include <iostream>
int main()
{std::cout << _TEST_ << std::endl;
}` [Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/8WU2tTf_Y)

Comment: Thanks, any idea why my code wasn't working?

Comment: Sidenote: Identifiers starting with an underscore are reserved in the global namespace and may not be used as the name of a macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"_TEST_"` is a **string literal** and not a macro. So no macro replacement will be done due to `"_TEST_"`. To achieve your expected output you need to remove the surrounding double quotes and also change the macro to as shown below

```
//-------------vvvvvv--->double quotes added here
#define _TEST_ "test" 
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
//-------------------vvvvvv---------------> not withing quotes
        std::cout << _TEST_ << std::endl;
}
```

The output of the above modified program is:

```
test
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/74mvHVaVe)

##### Explanation

In the modified program, the macro `_TEST_` stands for the string literal `"test"`. And thus when we use that macro in the statement `std::cout << _TEST_ << std::endl;`, it will be replaced by the string literal, producing the expected output.

Answer (score 7):

Macro expansion in the C/C++ preprocessor only happens to tokens. Variables names, for instance, are tokens. But the inside of a string is not a token; it's a part of a larger token (namely, the string literal itself).

If you want the macro to expand to something within quotation marks, you need to use [stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.3/cpp/Stringification.html).

```
#define xstr(x) str(x)
#define str(x) #x
#define _TEST_ test
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        std::cout << xstr(_TEST_) << std::endl;
}
```

You can read the above link for why we need those extra two layers of indirection (`xstr` and `str`), but the basic idea is that `#` itself doesn't do macro expansion, so by calling `xstr`, we force a macro expansion of the argument (`_TEST_` into `test`, namely), and then *separately* we call `str` to stringify that. If we had just called `str` directly, it would see `#_TEST_` and *not* perform macro expansion.